# Threads pausing and resuming c#

Tags: c#, .net, multithreading

I've got several threads ,how can I pause/resume them?

---

From duplicate question:

How can i pause 5 threads, and to remember their status. Because one of them is eating another is thinking, etc.

Comment: If you think you need to Pause threads, you've got problems you're not aware of.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

If you're using `System.Threading.Thread`, then you can call `Suspend` and `Resume`.  This, however is not recommended.  There's no telling what a thread might be doing when you call `Suspend`.  If you call `Suspend` while the thread holds a lock, for example, or has a file open for exclusive access, nothing else will be able to access the locked resource.

As the documentation for [Thread.Suspend](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.thread.resume.aspx) says:

> Do not use the Suspend and Resume
>   methods to synchronize the activities
>   of threads. You have no way of knowing
>   what code a thread is executing when
>   you suspend it. If you suspend a
>   thread while it holds locks during a
>   security permission evaluation, other
>   threads in the AppDomain might be
>   blocked. If you suspend a thread while
>   it is executing a class constructor,
>   other threads in the AppDomain that
>   attempt to use that class are blocked.
>   Deadlocks can occur very easily.

Typically, you control threads' activity using synchronization primitives like events.  A thread will wait on an event (look into `AutoResetEvent` and `ManualResetEvent`).  Or, if a thread is servicing a queue, you'll use something like `BlockingCollection` so that the thread can wait for something to be put into the queue.  All of these non-busy wait techniques are much better than arbitrarily suspending and restarting a thread, and don't suffer from the potential disastrous consequences.

Answer (score 2):

You have to use synchronisation techniques

[MSDN Thread Synchronization](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms173179(v=vs.80).aspx)

Comment: That document is very old -- 2005.  As other answers mentioned, you probably want to use threadsafe queues or some such to achieve your actual goal, rather than adding a layer of arbitrary and error prone synchronization with event wait primitives.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10721148/how-to-implement-thread-safe-queues is a pretty good recap of the topic

Answer (score 2):

Have a look at [Monitor.Wait](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.monitor.wait.aspx) and [Monitor.Pulse](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.monitor.pulse.aspx) in the first instance- Marc Gravell has a [nice example used in a queue here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/530211/creating-a-blocking-queuet-in-net/530228#530228).

In it quite likely that you want to consider using a [Producer/Consumer](http://www.albahari.com/threading/part4.aspx#_Wait_Pulse_Producer_Consumer_Queue) queue.

Answer (score 1):

In the main thread:

```
ManualResetEvent re = new ManualResetEvent(true);
```

In all the threads, at "strategic" points:

```
re.WaitOne();
```

In the main thread, to stop the threads:

```
re.Reset();
```

and to restart:

```
re.Set();
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `Suspend()` and `Resume()`.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.thread.resume.aspx

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.thread.suspend.aspx

You can also read:

[What are alternative ways to suspend and resume a thread?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/382173/what-are-alternative-ways-to-suspend-and-resume-a-thread)