# Alternate way for Thread.Suspend() and Thread.Resume();

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, multithreading

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [What are alternative ways to suspend and resume a thread?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/382173/what-are-alternative-ways-to-suspend-and-resume-a-thread)

In my work I previously used `Thread.Suspend();` And `Thread.Resume();` to suspend and resume the work done by the thread. But Now while compiling it says `Thread.Suspend();` And `Thread.Resume();` are obsolete and deprecated.

Is there any way to suspend and resume work..??

Comment: The best solution kind of depends what your thread is actually doing

Comment: I'll just put this in an answer as I can't add comments yet. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/382173/what-are-alternative-ways-to-suspend-and-resume-a-thread

Answer (score 0):

You could define a variable outside of the thread which can be read by the thread to determinate whether to work or stop.