# Thread.Resume Obsolete or decprecated: How to resume a suspended thread without using System.Threading.Thread.Resume?

Tags: .net, multithreading, delphi-prism, oxygene

Here is how I resume a suspended thread.

```
  if SerialThread.ThreadState = ThreadState.Suspended then
    SerialThread.Resume;
```

Although the above code doesn't raise compiler error or syntax error, it does however raise warning as follows;

> TSerialIndicator.pas(77,18): warning PW3: Obsolete: "System.Threading.Thread.Resume has been deprecated.  Please use other classes in System.Threading, such as Monitor, Mutex, Event, and Semaphore, to synchronize Threads or protect resources.

So, what is the proper way in .NET to resume a suspended thread?

Comment: `Thread.Suspend()` is also deprecated.

Comment: @SLaks, Yes, you are right. Does this mean one shouldn't use them for they may cause problem in your program? Except for the warning, the program seem to be okay with it. However, I am running into problems.

Comment: Suspending and resuming threads are inherently dangerous and unsafe operations.  You shouldn't do either.

Comment: @Slaks okay...So what do you suggest? Thanks.

Comment: What do I suggest for what?

Comment: @Slaks, I thought you would have suggestion as to how I should be doing this. If they are unsafe, how do you do that then without using them.

Comment: @digitalanalog post a *new* question describing *what you're trying to achieve* by suspending/resuming threads. You'll probably receive several good advices on the alternatives.

Comment: @AntonKovalenko, I thought the question was clear. I am asking for an alternative if compiler is warning that Suspend and Resume methods are obsolete or deprecated.

Comment: @digitalanalog the **thing** you're trying to do is deprecated, not just methods. You can go ahead and ignore the warnings, or you can *solve your real problem* (...if only we knew it) in some other way.

Comment: @digitalanalog maybe this can help http://stackoverflow.com/questions/382173/what-are-alternative-ways-to-suspend-and-resume-a-thread

Comment: @digitalanalog: The entire _concept_ of suspending and resuming a thread is inherently dangerous.  You need to do something completely different.  What problem are you trying to solve?

Answer (score 0):

AutoResetEvent is great for "suspending" a thread, your thread code just calls event.Wait till it has something to, when the caller calls event.Set() which breaks the wait.